# Limiting search space around line segment via rectangular buffer

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, image-processing

I have 2D line segments extracted from an image. So i know end point coordinates of them. also, i have some reference 2d line segments. Both line segments are now in vector form. comparing to reference and extracted lines,I have huge amount of extracted lines segments.

What i want to do is to find corresponding line segment for each reference line from my extraction. that is I want to match line segments. But, to reduce the search area i wish to limit it in such a way that by defining a buffer zone around a reference line segment.

> (1) My first question is how can i implement this buffer case with c++
>   as i am lacking with geometric theories.

Note: I dont want to use a bounding box and looking for a rectangular buffer which orient along the reference line.

> (2) my second question is, if i know the rectangular buffer limits,
>   then which type of concept should i use to avoid unnecessary searches
>   of line segments.

please do not think this as home work and i am really struggling because of my poor mathematics. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "conjugate line segment"?

Comment: @rschwieb: i mean corresponding

Comment: This sounds like a question for Stack Overflow with an "algorithms" tag, not really a math question.  I think you will also want to add more detail about what you want to do, because I don't understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding"?

Comment: @rschwieb: i want to get best matching extracted line segment to each reference line segment.

Comment: @all: i was trying to add a photo. but as i dont have 10 points i couldn't sorry.

Comment: Reducing search area sounds like some form of [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) might suite your needs: use the center of a line as key into the quad tree, and when searching have a search radius around the point you're actually looking for.